# "First sentence should end with a period."

Tags: java, checkstyle

Java checkstyle confuses and baffles me.

```
package pmain;

/**
 * Some text here.
 */

public class Main {

}
```

This is literally all of the code I have. Checkstyle displays a "First sentence should end with a period." at the "/**".

Why does CheckStyle produce this warning?

Could the checkstyle config I'm required to use be broken? Am I doing something wrong? Is "Some text here" not the first sentence? Is "." not a period?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you remove the blank line between the comment and the class definition?

Comment: I can at least confirm that "." is a period. :D

Comment: I just tried and it does not make any difference if I remove the blank line between the comment and the class definition.

Comment: Try putting a period after the package statement. You'll get a compiler error, but does checkstyle shut up?

Comment: I'm also glad that "." is still a period. That would have been awkward. I even tried making the comment a grammatically correct sentence. Still nothing.

Comment: A period after the package statement still produces the checkstyle error at the same place in addition to the compiler error on the first line.

Comment: @DNA Whitespace between the Javadoc comment and the method is irrelevant.

Answer (score 30):

The first sentence should end with a dot.

```
/**
 *An abstract class that represents an algorithm.
 *
 * @author zhangtj
 *
 * @version 1.0
*/
```

Would pass.

Comment: I'm sure that this isn't the right place to ask about *why* this is a style recommendation, but where is that place?  Your example does in fact pass the check, but it's not a sentence (no verb).  I have to imagine that the spirit of the check is to enforce that it be a sentence.

Comment: The first sentence up to the dot is displayed in the method list of the Javadoc class overview. It is at least ugly if some entries end with a dot whereas others don't

Comment: See https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#firstsentence

Answer (score 6):

Just tested on my machine and actually can't reproduce: I don't get a warning with a dot at the end of the sentence. But once I remove it (and run checkstyle again), the rule is triggered correctly and I get the warning on the `/**` line.

The blank line after the comment doesn't make a difference.

Double-check that the dot is really a dot and not some other character that "looks" like a dot. And double-check that you really re-run checkstyle after you've changed the file. It will not perform checks automagically.

---

Maybe someone played with the checkstyle settings. Actually there are two properties that control this rule: `checkFirstSentence` which is either true or false and `endOfSentenceFormat` which is a regular expression and should match the period. But if the ruleset has redefined that property... ;)

**Further Reading**

- http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html

Comment: Also clean your screen. Sometimes that "dot" is a spec of food. Just saying.

Comment: I copy-pasted that code so whatever character it is, it's the same character in the code bit of my question. I also copy-pasted your first period to my code. I also re-ran checkstyle again. Nothing.

Comment: As I said in the question, I'm required to use a specific checksyle config for an assignment. I'm using a remote config that guides to [link](http://lab.cs.ttu.ee/filed/iti-cs.xml).

Comment: I've configured eclipse to use the same remote rules and still nothing. Can't reproduce with your sample and your rules. Sorry.

Comment: Haha, okay. Seems something is very weird. I'll have a chat with someone who knows checkstyle and can fiddle around with my computer. Thanks for helping me figure out this is an "errors and troubleshooting" problem and not a "I am terrible at programming" problem.

Answer (score 5):

This just annoyed me. To remove this add:

...

```
<module name="JavadocStyle">
   <property name="checkFirstSentence" value="false"/>
</module>
```

...

And also, for me I **TOTALLY** removed the `SummaryJavadoc` module.

in your checkstyle.xml to switch this check off.

See: 
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocStyle
&
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#SummaryJavadoc

Comment: It would be clearer if you made clear that *both* of these are required to remove this error. Removing `SummaryJavadoc` isn't just as a preference, it's actually **required as Step 2** to get rid of this sentence period error.

Answer (score 3):

Thin can be caused by space after end of the comment or '.'

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is related to the missing `.` at the end of the line. To fix this you need to override the `period` property. Its default value is the `.` character.

According to the latest [Checkstyle documentation](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_javadoc.html#SummaryJavadoc), this is the recommended configuration to get rid of the “`First sentence should end with a period.`” warning:

```
<module name="SummaryJavadoc">
    <property name="forbiddenSummaryFragments" value="^@return the *|^This method returns |^A [{]@code [a-zA-Z0-9]+[}]( is a )"/>
    <property name="period" value=""/>
</module>
```

**If the solution above does not work, you can use the following alternative solution:**

Override the default value of the `endOfSentenceFormat` property.

Default value:

```
([.?!:][ \t\n\r\f&lt;])|([.?!:]$)
```

New value, accepts any number and letter at the end of the line:

```
([.?!:][ \t\n\r\f&lt;])|([\d\w.?!:]$)
```

Complete Checksytle configuration:

```
<module name="JavadocStyle">
    <property name="scope" value="public"/>
    <property name="checkEmptyJavadoc" value="true"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="ANNOTATION_DEF, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF, CLASS_DEF, CTOR_DEF, ENUM_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, METHOD_DEF, PACKAGE_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF"/>
    <property name="endOfSentenceFormat" value="([.?!:][ \t\n\r\f&lt;])|([\d\w.?!:]$)"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use 2 lines to avoid this warning. For example:

```
/**
 * Let's call this as the first sentence,
 * here the second one.
*/
```