# maven build failure- Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin

Tags: maven-3, cdap

I am trying to build CDAP source code by following article from below location-

```
https://github.com/caskdata/cdap
```

But when I try mvn clean package, It will gives build error-

```
.
.
kConfigurer.java:69: First sentence should end with a period.
C:\Users\admin\cdap\cdap-api\src\main\java\co\cask\cdap\api\workflow\WorkflowForkNode.java:21: First sentence should end with a period.
C:\Users\admin\cdap\cdap-api\src\main\java\co\cask\cdap\api\workflow\WorkflowSpecification.java:30: First sentence should end with a period.
C:\Users\admin\cdap\cdap-api\src\main\java\co\cask\cdap\api\workflow\WorkflowToken.java:22: First sentence should end with a period.
Audit done.

[INFO]    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Cask Data Application Platform (CDAP) ............. SUCCESS    [1:52.768s]
[INFO] CDAP API .......................................... FAILURE [1:03.487s]
[INFO] CDAP Watchdog API ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Protocol ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Build Common ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Common ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Notifications APIs ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Explore Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Data-Fabric .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Watchdog ..................................... SKIPPED
 [INFO] CDAP Notifications ................................ SKIPPED
 [INFO] CDAP HBase 0.96 Compatibility ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Data-Fabric Tests ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Java Client .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Test Framework ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP App-Fabric ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Explore JDBC Driver .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Explore ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Unit Test Framework .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP CLI .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Security ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Gateway ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP UI ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Standalone ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Java Client Tests ............................ SKIPPED
 [INFO] CDAP CLI Tests .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Kafka Server ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP HBase 0.94 Compatibility ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP HBase 0.98 Compatibility ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Master ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Distributions ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Application Archetypes ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Spark Java Archetype ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Spark Scala Archetype ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Application Archetype ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] CDAP Integration Test Framework ................... SKIPPED
[INFO]   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4:35.198s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat May 23 18:56:07 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/100M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-  
 plugin:2.12.1:check (validate) on project cdap-api: Failed during checkstyle execution:
 There are 68 checkstyle errors. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,   please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :cdap-api C:\Users\admin\cdap>
```

Please suggest what may be cause of this build failure.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

> kConfigurer.java:69: First sentence should end with a period.
>
> C:\Users\admin\cdap\cdap-api\src\main\java\co\cask\cdap\api\workflow\WorkflowForkNode.java:21: First sentence should end with a period.
>
> C:\Users\admin\cdap\cdap-api\src\main\java\co\cask\cdap\api\workflow\WorkflowSpecification.java:30: First sentence should end with a period.
>
> C:\Users\admin\cdap\cdap-api\src\main\java\co\cask\cdap\api\workflow\WorkflowToken.java:22: First sentence should end with a period.

I think in the class kConfigurer.java on line 69, the first sentence in the comment should end with a full stop.

Similar with the other 3 statements.

Check out

["First sentence should end with a period."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129766/first-sentence-should-end-with-a-period)

or

http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=505624&start=0&mc=9

if you're confused.

Checkstyle is mostly there so your code looks uniform, so be aware it'll do this often. Thankfully it's usually simple to fix.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates a problem with checkstyle where the *First line with comment is not ending with a period* on the lines highlighted. However specific to this project, I don't see any error building from develop.

1) Are you not building from develop branch?

2) Have you modified the suppressions.xml file? - The suppressions.xml line number 30 has disabled this check < suppress checks="JavadocStyle" files=".*/src/(main|integration)/java/.*" / >. So unless you have modified that file, you should not be seeing this specific checkstyle error.

3) There is no file called kConfigurer.java in the project. Perhaps it is best to remove all the files not related to CDAP before giving it a try.

Thanks,

Sree