# Checkstyle: How to turn off "SummaryJavadoc: First sentence of Javadoc is missing an ending period."

Tags: javadoc, checkstyle

I'm having trouble turning off the CheckStyle error

```
SummaryJavadoc: First sentence of Javadoc is missing an ending period.
```

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36895321/1005607), the fix is

```
<module name="JavadocStyle">
   <property name="checkFirstSentence" value="false"/>
</module>
```

But after I put it in there was no effect, I was still getting the error.

Based on the message, the error is in **SummaryJavadoc** rather than **JavadocStyle**. So I tried putting that property inside `SummaryJavadoc`:

```
   <module name="SummaryJavadoc">
        <property name="checkFirstSentence" value="false"/>
        <property name="forbiddenSummaryFragments"
         value="^@return the *|^This method returns |^A [{]@code [a-zA-Z0-9]+[}]( is a )"/>
    </module>
```

But that completely broke CheckStyle, so I can't put it there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `checkFirstSentence` as `false` removes the violations for `First sentence of Javadoc is missing an ending period` for `JavadocStyle`. To remove `First sentence of Javadoc is missing an ending period` from `SummaryJavadoc`, set the `period` as nothing.

```
$ cat TestClass.java
public class TestClass {
    /** Example */
    void method() {
    }
}

$ cat TestConfig.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

    <module name="TreeWalker">
<module name="JavadocStyle">
   <property name="checkFirstSentence" value="false"/>
</module>
<module name="SummaryJavadoc">
   <property name="period" value=""/>
</module>
    </module>
</module>

$ java -jar checkstyle-8.20-all.jar -c TestConfig.xml TestClass.java
Starting audit...
Audit done.
```

Comment: It should as this logic happens in checkstyle itself, not the maven plugin which is what 3.1.0 represents.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it -- as the linked thread suggests, there's a Step 2: completely remove the `SummaryJavadoc` section. **This is required as part of the solution**. I thought that part of the answer was unrelated, just a preference.

Therefore, there are 2 steps to get rid of the `First sentence of Javadoc is missing an ending period` error in Checkstyle:

**STEP 1**

Add

```
<module name="JavadocStyle">
   <property name="checkFirstSentence" value="false"/>
</module>
```

**STEP 2**

Remove or comment out the whole `SummaryJavadoc` section:

```
    <!-- 
    <module name="SummaryJavadoc">
        <property name="forbiddenSummaryFragments"
         value="^@return the *|^This method returns |^A [{]@code [a-zA-Z0-9]+[}]( is a )"/>
    </module>
     -->
```